# How do I set raw IP mode on an LTE modem via Linux's API?

Tags: linux, driver

I am running OpenWrt and trying to manipulate the raw IP driver setting on a USB-connected LTE modem. It is using the module `qmi_wwan`. (*This question is not about setting the modem itself to raw IP mode, but the driver!*)

If I want to set raw IP mode for the driver, I can do this with the following command:

```
echo "Y" > /sys/class/net/$ifname/qmi/raw_ip
```

The trouble is, the [sysfs interface is unstable](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysfs-rules.html). If this were a GPIO interface, I'd use libgpiod, if it were I2C I'd use eg. sysctl calls. I had assumed that the API for `/sys/class/net` stuff was in `net/if.h` and friends, but I cannot find any mention of raw IP or QMI-related stuff in there.

Where is the header file for this setting in Linux (4.14 at the moment)?

Comment: The last para in [this commit message](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/1449167063-22703-5-git-send-email-bjorn@mork.no/) does not bode well for my quest.

Comment: `The trouble is, the sysfs interface is unstable` You seem to be overcaring. Just use it, no need to be anxious, it will work. And if an update happens to break it, you'll see driver changes and update your script.

Comment: @KamilCuk I take your point, but it also means a full `system()` call and error handling for the extra indirection, compared to a library call.

Comment: Indirection? `system` is a wrapper. Use `open` and `write` and `close`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I will, but I will **also** still grumble about the extra calls and error checking.

Comment: Well, it's 3 calls, it's the less then in other interfaces. [libgpiod - like 4 calls](https://github.com/starnight/libgpiod-example/blob/master/libgpiod-led/main.c). I2c = `open` + `ioctl` + `close` - also 3 calls. There is no extra calls - `open`+`write`+`close` is __the__ way of writing C code and communicating with kernel.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though there is no API exposed to do this. The [commit which added raw IP mode](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/usb/qmi_wwan.c?id=32f7adf633b9f99ad5089901bc7ebff57704aaa9) to `qmi_wwan` says (emphasis mine):

> The firmware setup is fully delegated to the QMI userspace
> management application, through simple tunneling of the QMI
> protocol. The driver will therefore not know which mode has been "negotiated" between firmware and userspace. **Allowing userspace to inform the driver of the result through a sysfs switch is considered a better alternative** than to change the well established clean delegation of firmware management to userspace.

So until this capability is exposed in some other way, sysfs is it.